# swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens swap to BNB even if I set in path WBNB

Tags: solidity, contract-development, pancakeswap

I have a deployed contract with two basic swap functions.

For the "buy" the contract swap WBNB-> Token

For the "sell" it use the same function(swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens). But it swap to BNB instead of WBNB when it does Token -> WBNB

```
 //Testnet addr wbnb
 address private wbnb = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;

 function buy(address token, uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin) external{

    if(msg.sender == me)
    {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = wbnb;//In my contract I use WBNB tokens balance.
        path[1] = token;

         uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amountIn, 
            amountOutMin,
            path, 
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
         
}     


function sell(address token, uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin) external {

    if(msg.sender == me)
    {           

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token;
        path[1] = wbnb;//In my contract I get BNB even if I use WBNB addr.
        
        
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
           amountIn, 
            amountOutMin,
            path, 
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        ); 
    }

}
```

Even in the transaction I see that WBNB has been swap, but BNB arrives at the contract, no WBNB

How can I get WBNB instead of BNB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` with `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`. They're both the exact same but the `forETH` version require the last member of the path to be WBNB and adds 2 lines of code to unwrap it before sending it to you

Comment: Also you should replace `if(msg.sender == me)`with `require(msg.sender == me)`. Rn anyone other than you sending tokens to contract would just lock the tokens away forever (`require` would prevent them to send tokens in the first place)